# Search element in html on the active tab (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create my own google chrome extention for searching  some information in html
Important think:  searching in active tab.

Example of my **popup.js**

```
chrome.tabs.query( {
active: true,
lastFocusedWindow: true},

function(array_of_Tabs) {
var tab = array_of_Tabs[0];

chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: "chrome.runtime.sendMessage(document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML));"});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML = request;});
```

My **manifest.json** file:

```
 {
 "name": "HTML opener",
 "description": "Open the current page in popup window",
 "version": "1.0",
 "permissions": [
 "activeTab"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
 "default_title": "HTML opener",
 "default_popup": "popup.html"
 },
 "manifest_version": 2
 }
```

And my **popup.html** looks like:

```
<style>
  body {
    min-width: 300px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
</style>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

And I havent any result. Is there any way to find text in html on current opened tab using chrome.tabs ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that automatically search the element `id=hour` on the current page *(tab)*.

***Note:** I also added some code to show the user an action icon.*

**manifest.json**

```
...
"page_action" :
{
    "default_icon" : "icon.png",
    "default_title" : "Icon title!"
},
"content_scripts" : [
{
  "matches" : [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "js" : ["contentscript.js"],
  "run_at" : "document_idle",
  "all_frames" : false
}
],
...
```

**contentscript.js**

```
if (document.getElementById('hour')) {
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({}, function(response) {});
    // You can do whatever you want here ...
}
```

**background.js**

```
function onRequest(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id); // Chrome will show a pageAction icon
    sendResponse({});
};

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onRequest);
```